# Pattern matching on Ints

Tags: function, haskell, types, functional-programming, pattern-matching

I am a beginner in learning Haskell, and I wanted to know if you could pattern match on `Int`s like so:

```
 add x 0 = x
 add x (1 + y) = 1 + x  + add x y,
```

Or maybe in this way:

```
 add x 0 = x
 add x (successor y) = 1 + x + add x y
```

Comment: If you feel there is a suitable answer below, please consider accepting it by clicking the tick, @user12596.

Answer (score 13):

There is an extension that lets you do that, but instead you should simply pattern match on `y`, and subtract `1` manually:

```haskell
add x y = 1 + x + add x (y - 1)
```

The extension is called `NPlusKPatterns`. If you *really* want to use it (keep in mind it's deprecated in haskell 2010), it can be enabled by either passing a `-XNPlusKPatterns` parameter to GHC, or putting a `{-# LANGUAGE NPlusKPatterns #-}` at the top of your file.

Answer (score 2):

Pattern matching isn't arbitrary case analysis. It's a disciplined, but limited form of case analysis, where the cases are the *constructors* of a data type.

In the specific case of pattern matching integers, the constructors are taken to be the integer *values*. So you can use integer values as the cases for pattern-matching:

```
foo 0 = ...
foo 2 = ...
foo x = ...
```

But you can't use arbitrary expressions. The following code is illegal:

```
foo (2 * x) = ...
foo (2 * x + 1) = ...
```

*You* may know that ever integer is either of the form `2 * x` or `2 * x + 1`. But the type system doesn't know.

Comment: To be fair, in haskell98 you could match for `(x + 5)`, and such match would fail for numbers less than 5, and succeed and subtract 5 for all other numbers. The functionality was found useless and was removed from haskell2010, and GHC supports it as an extension.

Answer (score 0):

The formatting of your code is a bit off so it is difficult to know what you're asking but you can using pattern matching for input of type Int. An example would be

```
add x 0 = x
add x y = x + y
```